# Using external data source with Leaflet / GeoJSON?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, geojson, markers

First of all, I've been looking everywhere and I have not found a functional solution.

I need to display the points from a data file exported from Qgis.

I tried Qgis2web, but I'd like to put everything up in the Leaflet from the beginning and then just update the data from Qgis.

Explorer does not report any errors, but it does not show points with markers.

Here is index:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <title>PinLeX</title>
        <style>
         html, body, #map {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
          }
        </style>
        <!--Leaflet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leafletmap.js"></script>
        <script src="data/PinLayer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map">
      <script>
       initmap(); 
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here map set (leafletmap.js):

```
var map;

  function initmap() {
    // set up the map
    map = new L.Map('map');

    // create the tile layer with correct attribution
    var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osmAttrib='Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
    var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
  minZoom: 8, 
  maxZoom: 18, 
  attribution: osmAttrib
  })    

    // start the map in defined location
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(48.974244, 14.478729),9);
    map.addLayer(osm);

  // PinLayer
  var pinpoint = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'markers/pinpoint.svg',
  iconSize: [26.599999999999998, 26.599999999999998],
  iconAnchor: [16, 37],
  popupAnchor: [0, -28]
  });

  L.geoJson(PinLayer, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: pinpoint});
    },
  }).addTo(map);
}
```

And here GeoJson (transformed to js - PinLayer.js)

```
var PinLayer = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "PinLayer",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null, "name": "Senovážné náměstí", "country": "Česká republika", "desc": "Popis není k dispozici.", "status": "v provozu", "photocell": "ne", "admin": "Statutární město České Budějovice (?)", "update": "7\/4\/2018", "spec": "České Budějovice", "type": "standartní pítko", "photo": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1611753.67562, 6270485.80685 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null, "name": "Katedrála sv. Mikuláše", "country": "Česká republika", "desc": "Popis není k dispozici.", "status": "v provozu", "photocell": "ne", "admin": "Statutární město České Budějovice (?)", "update": "12\/4\/2018", "spec": "České Budějovice", "type": "standartní pítko", "photo": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1611428.44996, 6270639.98718 ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: What is the coordinate system of PinLayer.js data?

Comment: Using anything else than EPSG:4326 in GeoJSON contravenes the standard and should be avoided. Leaflet does not support anything else than EPSG:4326 for GeoJSON data.

Comment: Yea, that is. Wrong coordinate system. Now works fine. Thanks, guys!